# Data encryption at DB and decryption using C# code

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, encryption

We have to encrypt a userid at the SQL Server level, then pass this encrypted value to C# via the query string and once C# reads it it will need to decrypt this (call a SQL Server function to achieve this).

Our encryption technique does not have to be really strong so we decided to go with `EncryptByPassPhrase` and `DecryptByPassPhrase`.

However I am having difficulty passing the decrypted value from C# to the SQL Server function in order for me to get back the decrypted string back.

SQL Server function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_DecryptString] 
     (@EncryptedString VARBINARY(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetValue VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @PassPhrase varchar(200) = 'key'

    SET @RetValue = DecryptByPassPhrase(@PassPhrase, @EncryptedString )    

    RETURN @RetValue
END
```

C# code that calls the decrypt function:

```
  object decryptedUserId = 0;               
  byte[] newByte = StrToByteArray(encryptedUserId);

  var conn = new SqlConnection(CONN_STRING);
  const string query = "select dbo.ufn_DecryptString(@EncryptedString);";

  conn.Open();

  var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@EncryptedString", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = newByte;

  decryptedUserId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();    

  conn.Close();

  return decryptedUserId;

  private static byte[] StrToByteArray(string strValue)
  {
      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      return encoding.GetBytes(strValue);
  }
```

I keep getting a blank object in `decryptedUserId` when I execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first cell, of the first row of the first table. You `RETURN @RetValue`, and don't `SELECT @RetValue` to have a first cell of a first row of a first table - alternately, you could set it via an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that helped in solving half the issue, however it seems from the above code whenever I pass the encoded string to SQL by converting to byte[] , the encoded string does not remain the same when I profile it in SQL , any idea why ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the length of the parameter, i.e `cmd.Parameters.Add("@EncryptedString", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 200).Value = newByte`